# xlinq throw null data? how can i solve it?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, linq

Hello again; i try to save xml data from xml file. How can i do that? if i use below codes, XmlStream return null "throw null". How can do that?

my data:

```
<list>
  <subscriber Type="Random">
    <name>yusuf</name>
    <surname>karatoprak</surname>
  </subscriber>
</list>
```

```
 public static XDocument GetRawsSnippetAsXDocuments()
       {
           Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
           Stream xmlStream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("XlinqTest1.User.xml");
           if (xmlStream == null)
           {
               throw new NullReferenceException("Hata!!!");
           }
           XDocument xmlDocument = XDocument.Load(XmlReader.Create(xmlStream));

           return xmlDocument;
       }
```

Main Program:

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument document = XmlHelper.GetRawsSnippetAsXDocuments();
            var listCount = document.Descendants("list").Count();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're loading the assembly resource incorrectly. Instead of just User.xml, you need *yourNamespace*.User.xml. If your resource is inside a folder within the project, that will be reflected in the final name as well.

[Check out this example.](http://www.attilan.com/2006/08/accessing_embedded_resources_u.php)

Comment: Are you compiling with the XML file set as an embedded resource?